# How select images for diferents actions in dataTable?

Tags: jquery, datatables, jquery-selectors

I made a dataTable and in each row contains data item and two icons images, one for mark the item as favourite and the other icon is for report an unapropiated item by clicking on it. So, there are two diferents action depends on the icon clicked. In did the jquery code for mark as favourite

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
            var table = $('#myTable').DataTable();
             $('#myTable tbody').on( 'click', 'img', function () {
            //mark as favourite
             }
```

but this works with both icons, how can I discriminate between them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are selecting both of them by using only img tag. You need to add a classname  to distinguish between actions.

And a custom data-attribute like data-id attribute, it's value we could use later to identify the targeted item (Database ID) and that could be added when you are populating your Datatable() with ajax ([like here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59829528/datatable-custom-delete-column/59830979#59830979)) or with php...

```
<img src="fav.png" class="fav" data-id="12"><img src="flag.png" class="flag" data-id="13">
```

And in your script :

```
         $(document).ready(function() {
                    var table = $('#myTable').DataTable();
                     $('#myTable tbody').on( 'click', '.fav', function () {
                    //mark as favourite 
    //to use the ID of that item you need another row identifier for your function 
    var id=$(this).data('id');
                     }
                     $('#myTable tbody').on( 'click', '.flag', function () {
                    //Report that...
    var id=$(this).data('id');
                     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution after reading https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/
Giving different class names to the images then you are allowed to select them.

```
<img class='fv'>
```

for favourite icon and

```
<img class='cs'>
```

for the censoring icon, then you can select them accordingly.

```
$('#myTable tbody').on( 'click', 'img.fv', function () {
        //mark as favourite
         }
$('#myTable tbody').on( 'click', 'img.cs', function () {
        //mark as unapropiated
         }
```

that's all.